# piping multiple statements together only performs first command

Tags: c, shell, pipe

*edit half of the problem has been fixed and the question has been edited to reflect that fixing. I still am only seeing this perform the first command in a series of pipes.*

I am stuck on the very last thing in my shell that I am making from scratch. I want to be able to parse commands like `"finger | tail -n +2 | cut -c1-8 | uniq | sort"` and I think that I am close. What I have right now, when given that line as an array of strings, only executes the "finger" part.

Here is the part of code that isn't working as it needs to be, I've narrowed it down to just this for loop and the part after:

```
mypipe[2];
//start out with stdin
oldinfd = 0;


   //run the beginning commands. connect in/out of pipes to eachother.
   for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){

      pipe(mypipe);

      processline(commands[i], oldinfd, mypipe[1]); //doesn't wait on children

      close(mypipe[1]);

      oldinfd = mypipe[0];

   }

   //run the final command, put output into stdout
   processline(commands[max], oldinfd, 1);  //waits on children

   ...
```

This loop runs the program and should end up looking like this:

stdin -> [0]pipe[write] -> [read]pipe[write] -> ... ->[read]pipe[1] -> stdout

My processline function takes in a line ('finger') and `exec`s it. for instance, `processline("finger", 0, 1)` run the `finger` command without flaws. For the purposes of this question assume that processline works perfectly, what I'm having troubles with is how I'm using the pipes and their write and read ends.

Also with print statements, I have confirmed that the correct words are being sent to the correct parts. (the for loop receives "finger", "tail -n +2", "cut -c1-8", and "uniq", while the commands[max] that the last line receives is "sort").

Comment: Well, at minimum, it appears that you close the shell's standard input on the first iteration of  the loop presented.  That would indeed interfere with receiving further input from it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see what you mean there, I changed it and updated the question. I had been closing it before setting it, so it would default to 0 or 3 and would keep switching back and forth, now it does a steady 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Does `processline` wait for the child process that it presumably creates?  That can appear to work if none of the children produce very much output, but the moment one of them completely fills its output pipe buffer, the entire pipeline will deadlock.  You must start _all_ of the child processes in a pipeline before you wait for _any_ of them.

Comment: @zwol whenever I call processline from this loop, I have a variable set to tell it not to wait on any children. Once I call the final one (with the commands[max]), then it is allowed to wait on children.

Comment: You have not presented enough information for us to answer the (revised) question.  There is a variety of missing details, any one of which could explain the problem, from the values taken by your variables to the implementation of `processline()`, and possibly even things we don't have any hint to look for.  If you want help then prepare a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and edit it into the question.